# JBoss 7 on FreeBSD

Tags: jboss7.x, freebsd

I heard that JBoss 7 is not certified for FreeBSD - is that correct?

Where can I find a list of supported platforms? (I spent some time googling, but was not successful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking there is no certified OS for JBoss 7 as only JBoss EAP 6 is supported by Red Hat.

The supported configuration for JBoss EAP 6 (the supported version of community JBoss 7) can be found here: https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/articles/111663

As JBoss is pure java application, a compliant JDK is enough to have a supported system.  So if you have the Oracle or IBM JDK running on FreeBSD is will be supported by Red Hat.  But they haven't test them with JBoss.

Any way if you want Red Hat support for the EAP you better check with there representative to discus the extends of the support (if the FreeBSD JDK have some compliance bug, they will probably send you back to the JDK supplier.  If you chose RHEL with OpenJDK you will have one supplier to blame for any software stack issue, no redirect to another suplier.)

For community JBoss as for other platform, you will be responsible to make it work with your stack.  An good first test can be performed by running the standard compliance tests included in the JBoss sources, if it runs on your target platform and JDK it is a good sign that JBoss is working on it.

Answer (score 0):

**Certified Support as per Redhat only goes up to 6:**
https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/articles/111663

However if you look back at the release docs they have not changed. OS's are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but the question was not about if it runs on FreeBSD, but about certification from JBoss/RedHat for FreeBSD.